# unable to test application in android device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an mobile application using IBM MobileFirst Plaform.

When I test the app in the browser, Mobile simulator and android emulator the application is working fine. When I deploy the apk file in my android device and run the application is not running. when I checked the logcat I have the following error.

> I/Web Console(20334): processMessage failed: Message: F09
>   WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin1268447688
>   {"wlFailureStatus":"UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","status":500,"responseText":"","statusText":"The
>   service is currently not available."} at
>   file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js:1063

Both my laptop and Mobile are connected to same wifi network

Answer (score 0):

Your server is likely set to "localhost".

1. Open the Servers view in Eclipse
2. Double-click on "MobileFirst Development Server"
3. Change the host value to the IP address of your machine (if you have several IP addresses, be sure you use the correct one)
4. Re-start the server (should happen automatically after saving your changes in step 3)
5. Re-build the application by right-clicking on the app folder > Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server (this ensures the set IP address will propogate to the project's wlclient.properties file)
6. Delete the application from the device
7. Re-install the newly generated application (from step 5)

Verify that the application is now able to connect to the MFP Server.

Comment: D/wl.request(28874): WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://192.168.100.16:10080/CustomLoginModule/authorization/v1/clients/instance
 D/dalvikvm(28874): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5784K, 41% free 8825K/14844K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 59msD/wl.certManager(28874): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
 D/NONE(28874): Client registration failed with error:"status":500,"responseHeaders":},"responseText":"","invocationContext":null} E/NONE(28874): [/apps/services/api/CustomLoginModule/android/query]failure.state:500, response:undefined

Comment: How is your mobile device connected to the network?  Via WiFi (on your own network), or are you using the mobile carrier's data network?  If you're using the mobile carrier's data network, you won't be able to contact "192.168.100.16", which is a non-public IP address.

Comment: If the mobile device is connected via WiFi (to your network, with a "192.168.100.xxx" IP address), check to see if a host firewall (like "iptables" if are on Linux, Windows Firewall if you're on a Windows system, etc.) is blocking the incoming traffic to port 10080 from outside hosts.

Comment: Hi I am connecting it through the a wifi network and the ip of my laptop was 192.168.100.16 and the ip in my mobile was 192.168.100.28 Also I was able to connect the same way one week back and suddenly I am started facing this issue

Comment: @GopiNath have tried opening the MFP Console in Mobile browser [http://192.168.100.16:10080/worklightconsole]

Comment: @dhineshsundar yes i am able to access the worklight console  from mobile browser

Comment: @GopiNath, are you trying to connect server using **https** protocol from Mobile?

Comment: @GopiNath This happens to me constantly... still can't figure out why it happens. Really slowing down production.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check wlclient.properties file in native android folder??
In that file check  wlserverhost and wlserver port. Before that if you deploy your app to any remote server that ip address and port number should configured for android environment.
Change that IP address and port number by un-check Build the application to work with a different Mobile first server...
Re build the application to the local mobile first server..

Answer (score 0):

Para eclipse luna 4.4.0 and WORKLIGHT 6.3

```
 function wlCommonInit() {

 //set url de conexion para Android

 var environment = WL.Client.getEnvironment();

 if (environment == WL.Environment.ANDROID) {

 WL.App.setServerUrl("https://<SERVER>:          <PORT>/<contextPATH>",setServerURLSuccess, setServerURLFailure);

   }
```

........

};

and create two methods

```
function setServerURLSuccess() {
  // Display the newly set server URL.
  //alert(getServerURL());
}

function setServerURLFailure() {
WL.SimpleDialog.show(
    "Change Server URL", "Failed setting Server URL", 
    [{
        text: "Close", handler: function() {}
    }]
 )
}
```

Saludos!!!