# Cannot Run App from Real Device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to test my application in real device with MobileFirst 7.0. It works perfectly in emulator and web browser.

It generates this error when running from device upon calling http adapter:

```
06-17 18:42:29.358: D/CordovaActivity(7679): Resuming the App
06-17 18:42:29.398: D/WLClient(7679): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityStarted in WLClient.java:1434 :: on activity started com.Delivery.Delivery
06-17 18:42:29.408: D/WLClient(7679): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityResumed in WLClient.java:1423 :: on activity resumed com.Delivery.Delivery . activity count = 1
06-17 18:42:33.698: W/PluginManager(7679): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to NativeBusyIndicator.show blocked the main thread for 178ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-17 18:42:33.818: D/NONE(7679): establishSSLClientAuth
06-17 18:42:33.858: W/PluginManager(7679): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to UserAuth.init blocked the main thread for 18ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-17 18:42:33.998: W/PluginManager(7679): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to UserAuth.isCertificateExists blocked the main thread for 83ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-17 18:42:34.028: D/NONE(7679): establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
06-17 18:42:34.048: D/NONE(7679): Request [/apps/services/api/Delivery/android/query]
06-17 18:42:34.708: W/PluginManager(7679): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader blocked the main thread for 625ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-17 18:42:34.748: D/wl.request(7679): WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://192.168.43.73:10080/Delivery/authorization/v1/clients/instance
06-17 18:42:45.228: D/wl.certManager(7679): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
06-17 18:42:45.358: W/PluginManager(7679): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.deleteAllAuthData blocked the main thread for 110ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-17 18:42:45.368: D/wl.certManager(7679): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
06-17 18:42:45.638: W/PluginManager(7679): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader blocked the main thread for 271ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-17 18:42:45.638: D/wl.request(7679): WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://192.168.43.73:10080/Delivery/authorization/v1/clients/instance
06-17 18:42:55.838: D/wl.certManager(7679): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
06-17 18:42:55.868: D/NONE(7679): Client registration failed with error: {"status":500,"responseHeaders":{},"responseText":"","invocationContext":null}
06-17 18:42:55.878: E/NONE(7679): [/apps/services/api/Delivery/android/query] failure. state: 500, response: undefined
```

Tried to do the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038678/unable-to-test-application-in-android-device) but no luck.

Tried to delete my device from MobileFirst console, delete app from device and run the Android project again but now my device cannot appear in console.

Any advise what could be wrong?

**Note**:

I tethered my phone to my laptop to gain internet connection and set the IP of MF server to my laptop IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so according to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038678/unable-to-test-application-in-android-device), I really can't use tethering. When I use wifi, it works as expected.

I am not sure why this happens because from my phone can ping and telnet the IP and port of MobileFirst server but the app can't work.